# background is divided for some reason

Tags: html, css

can someone take a look at my webpage and help me figure out what is wrong 
for some a reason the background gradient is divided and start a new one again.

I want the gradient to continue to the entire page.

this is the html

https://www.csupomona.edu/~lannguyen/Test/Template.html

this is the css for it

https://www.csupomona.edu/~lannguyen/Test/mystyle.css

Thanks

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get a tool like Firebug for Firefox and learn to use it.  It makes finding issues like this simple.

The answer is clear, once you have the right tool: the gradient, which is applied to the body element, does not extend all the way down because the body element does not go the full height of the browser.

Add:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

and it will be fixed.

Comment: wow that was fast, thanks